# Loading a Blob (PDF) with Angularjs into iFrame Filename?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello currently I'm loading a blob via angularjs into a iframe, however when saving the blob it has some wierd filenames is there a way to specify it?
Here is my code:

```
let id = $routeParams.id;
$http({
  url: `http://..../${id}/`,
  method: 'GET',
  data: {},
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success((data, status, headers, config) => {
  var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var objectUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
  this.blob = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(objectUrl);
});
```

Comment: I don't know Angular, but how do you save the blob? In js, there is no way to set the name of an objectURL

Comment: currently I think I could somehow feed it to pdf.js to have the functionalitiy i wanted